# RLS Policy doesn't applied for table in PostgreSQL while the RLS has been enabled

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I've trying to apply RLS on my PostgreSQL 14. But it seems didn't work. Here it's my SQL (i run it on PgAdmin4):

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.employee
(
    tenant_id character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    username character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT employee_pkey PRIMARY KEY (username)
)

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS employee
    OWNER to postgres;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS employee
    ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY employee_tenant_isolation_policy
    ON employee
    AS PERMISSIVE
    FOR ALL
    TO public
    USING (((tenant_id)::text = ((current_setting('app.tenant_id'::text))::character varying)::text));
```

i'm also already have to insert the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO public.employee(
    tenant_id, username)
    VALUES ('tenant1', 'tenant1');
INSERT INTO public.employee(
    tenant_id, username)
    VALUES ('tenant2', 'tenant2');
```

As you can see, i have enabled the RLS and created the policy. But, when i try this query:

```sql
SET app.tenant_id to 'tenant1';
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

I got two values (tenant1, and tenant2). I expect it to only return row with 'tenant1' values.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you connected as `postgres`?

Comment: yes. i connected as 'postgres'

Comment: You shouldn't be using the superuser at all. The tables should be owned (and created) by a regular user. Only use `postgres` for DBA tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html), superusers bypass RLS:

> Superusers and roles with the BYPASSRLS attribute always bypass the row security system when accessing a table. Table owners normally bypass row security as well, though a table owner can choose to be subject to row security with ALTER TABLE ... FORCE ROW LEVEL SECURITY.

If you create a non-superuser, you should be able to see the filtering:

```
edb=# create user foobar with login;
CREATE ROLE
edb=# grant select on employee to foobar;
GRANT
edb=# \c edb foobar;
You are now connected to database "edb" as user "foobar".
edb=> SET app.tenant_id to 'tenant1';
SET
edb=> select * from employee ;
 tenant_id | username 
-----------+----------
 tenant1   | tenant1
(1 row)
```